# How to get my input in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I getting input through openfiledialog , when i select the image from it , i want to display that image in picturebox1 and when i click on the other button it should start process my image

Here is my code which is working fine

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                info.FileName = "console.exe";
                info.Arguments = fileName;
                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();

            }
```

picturebox1

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

But in this code when i select the image through dialogbox it is selected and process started and output image appears , i want that when i select the image it should come to picturebox1 and then when i click on other button it should start processing the WK01

Comment: Do you mean to upload it into memory (Image.FromFile()) and then pass to picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create two functions one is for invoking `OpenFileDialog` and assigning the selected picture to `PictureBox` , another is for processing your image.

code is as below:

```
private string fileName = "";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fileName; 
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                info.FileName = "console.exe";
                info.Arguments = fileName;
                Process p = new Process();

                p.StartInfo = info;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();

            }
```

This is as per my assumption and if you need anything more please let me know.

Comment: Can you inform me why you didn't use this `string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;`

Comment: @Ahmad: if you declare string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName; inside one function, which will not be avialable on second function where you need to process that image as it becomes a local variable to first function.